# I want to extract data from website and refresh that data in 15 days , and whenever website get updated dataset should be updated too. How approach it

Tags: azure, web-scraping, automation, azure-functions, scheduled-tasks

Have to extract data from website and schedule it refresh after every 15 days .After every update have to send mail aboutthat update to specific person. Any suggestions,  how should I approach this problem.

I am using scrapy for web scrapping and store in azure blob and write that web scrapping script in Azure function and schedule refresh. And also trigger for email.